# when we post data using angular16 project but data will not be save in node rest Api (node ,express ,mongo )

Tags: mongodb, express

i am new mean project and this will be learning form youtube

1. rest Api URL

http://localhost:9003/master/saveid?created_by=munesh&id_code=AR&id_name=AREA&id_status=true&id_value=1

nodejs  code

```
    api.post('/saveid', function (req, res) {
       
        var generate_id = new GenerateID1({
            id_name         : req.body.id_name,
            id_code         : req.body.id_code,
            id_value        : req.body.id_value,
            status          : req.body.status,
            created_by      : req.body.created_by,
            created_date    : Date.now()

        });

        generate_id.save(function (err, respo) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(400).json({ "message": "Data not saved successfully" });
            }
            else {
               
                res.status(200).json({ "message": message });
            }
        });






    });
```

error shows

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id_name')
    at D:\mishti\minshiWeb\projects\web_server\app\routes\masterapi.js:44:40
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
```

not read data form req

```
req.body.id_name,
```

Comment: Please share the front end code that calls this API also!

Comment: Inside the `api.post('/saveid'` callback please `console.log('body=', req.body)` to see what was actually sent and parsed.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the values as query parameters not in the post body, please check the below example.

```
ngOnInit() {
    const body = { title: 'Angular POST Request Example' };
    this.http.post<any>('https://reqres.in/api/posts', body).subscribe(data => {
        this.postId = data.id;
    });
}
```

Reference: [angular http examples](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/11/21/angular-http-post-request-examples)